# Trouble installing RJSONIO on R 3.0.2 and Debian wheezy 7.3

Tags: r, gcc

I'm newbie to R.

I just successfully installed R according to
http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/README.html
The target OS is Debian wheezy 7.3.

Then I successfully installed RStudio.

Then I tried to install packages needed for RHadoop according to following page. 
http://bighadoop.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/r-and-hadoop-data-analysis-rhadoop/
The only difference is that I installed packages with newer version numbers.
The detail steps are:

`R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz`
`R CMD INSTALL stringr_0.6.2.tar.gz`
`R CMD INSTALL plyr_1.8.tar.gz`
`R CMD INSTALL functional_0.4.tar.gz`
`R CMD INSTALL digest_0.6.4.tar.gz`

But failed at the following step:

`R CMD check RJSONIO_1.0-3.tar.gz`

```
rlibjson.c: In function 'R_json_stream_parse':
rlibjson.c:449:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'json_new_stream' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from Rlibjson.h:1:0,
                 from rlibjson.c:1:
./libjson/libjson.h:68:18: note: expected 'json_stream_callback_t' but argument is of type 'void (*)(void *)'
rlibjson.c:449:5: error: too few arguments to function 'json_new_stream'
```

My gcc version is gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5).
Is there any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `install.packages("RJSONIO", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R", type="source")` ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem:

`# locate libjson.h`
/usr/include/libjson/libjson.h
/usr/local/include/libjson/libjson.h

`# tar zcvf libjson.h.tar.gz /usr/include/libjson/libjson.h /usr/local/include/libjson/libjson.h`
`# rm /usr/include/libjson/libjson.h /usr/local/include/libjson/libjson.h`
`# R CMD check RJSONIO_1.0-3.tar.gz`

Done

Then replace libjson.h to where it should be.

It seems that libjson.h that already exists conflicts with RJSONIO.

Thanks.

Comment: You should create a new question asking what `libjson.h` is used for by Debian, and whether replacing it will cause any conflicts.