# What libjson.h is used for Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

I found the following two `libjson.h` in my Debian wheezy 7.3:

```
/usr/include/libjson/libjson.h
/usr/local/include/libjson/libjson.h
```

Seems to conflict with RJSONIO package for R, as shown in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948085/trouble-installing-rjsonio-on-r-3-0-2-and-debian-wheezy-7-3/20962682).

And I have two questions about that:

- Does any one know what `libjson.h` is for Debian?
- How can I know which package `/usr/include/libjson/libjson.h` belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

To find the package name of a certain file you can use **dpkg** command with **-S**.

Example:

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/libjson/libjson.h
```

Comment: thanks, @Kesara ,
But it seems that I installed some json related packages from source tarball. dpkg can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want `json.h` instead of `libjson.h`.

Second, you can search at http://packages.debian.org -- and searching for packages containing a filepath ending in `json.h` yields [this long list](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=json.h&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any)

Lastly, for what it is worth, I have the `libjson-c-dev` package installed. It provide `/usr/include/json-c/json.h`, and the standard CRAN packages for JSON install fine.

Comment: I finally found that I installed libjson from source code (libjson_7.6.1.zip) for graphlabapi since it need libjson (>=7.6.0) and I cannot find it in apt-cache search.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apt-file to search for a file name in all available packages.

```
apt install apt-file
apt update
```

Then you can use apt-file:

```
apt-file search "json.h"
```